# How to include the spec of a CRD into another CRD?

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I am building an operator using Kubebuilder which will work with a CRD which contains a few custom fields and also all fields of an [Argo `WorkflowTemplate`](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#workflowtemplate). The fields will be essentially all the fields of an [Argo `Workflow`](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#workflow) as the fields in the spec are the same apart from one field which I don't care about.  The operator will use the `WorkflowTemplate` fields to create an actual Argo `WorkflowTemplate` resource, but before that it needs to perform some actions on the custom fields. How can I include all the fields of the `WorkflowTemplate` in my CRD without literally copying all the fields and manually pasting it in the Spec of my CRD?

I tried having this in my CRD(I just added certain other fields that are not related to the problem at hand)

```golang
import (
    wfv1 "github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/v3/pkg/apis/workflow/v1alpha1"
)

type DefinitionSpec struct {
    Field1       string            `json:"field1,omitempty"`
    Field2       string            `json:"field2,omitempty"`
    WorkflowSpec wfv1.WorkflowSpec `json:",inline"`
}
```

If I do this, I get this error while installing the CRD

```sh
$ make install
/Users/mbtamuli/workspace/argo-workflow-operator/bin/controller-gen rbac:roleName=manager-role crd webhook paths="./..." output:crd:artifacts:config=config/crd/bases
/Users/mbtamuli/workspace/argo-workflow-operator/bin/kustomize build config/crd | kubectl apply -f -
The CustomResourceDefinition "definitions.mriyam.dev" is invalid:
* metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templateDefaults].properties[dag].properties[tasks].items.properties[inline].type: Required value: must not be empty for specified object fields
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templateDefaults].properties[steps].items.items: Required value: must be specified
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templates].items.properties[dag].properties[tasks].items.properties[inline].type: Required value: must not be empty for specified object fields
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templates].items.properties[steps].items.items: Required value: must be specified
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I found out from other SO and GitHub issues that I can get around the annotations issue by using create instead of apply.

```
$ bin/kustomize build config/crd | kubectl create -f -
+ kubectl create -f -
The CustomResourceDefinition "definitions.mriyam.dev" is invalid:
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templateDefaults].properties[dag].properties[tasks].items.properties[inline].type: Required value: must not be empty for specified object fields
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templateDefaults].properties[steps].items.items: Required value: must be specified
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templates].items.properties[dag].properties[tasks].items.properties[inline].type: Required value: must not be empty for specified object fields
* spec.validation.openAPIV3Schema.properties[spec].properties[templates].items.properties[steps].items.items: Required value: must be specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem when wrapping the Argo Workflows CRD and then I discovered that the Argo Workflows project avoids the issues by removing CRD validation:

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/hack/crds.go

The most important part is the following function:

```golang
func removeCRDValidation(filename string) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Clean(filename))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    crd := make(obj)
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &crd)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    spec := crd["spec"].(obj)
    versions := spec["versions"].([]interface{})
    version := versions[0].(obj)
    properties := version["schema"].(obj)["openAPIV3Schema"].(obj)["properties"].(obj)
    for k := range properties {
        if k == "spec" || k == "status" {
            properties[k] = obj{"type": "object", "x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields": true, "x-kubernetes-map-type": "atomic"}
        }
    }
    data, err = yaml.Marshal(crd)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, data, 0o600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Essentially they override the CRD spec, and set `x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields` to true to ensure that the Kubernetes API accepts requests without checking the fields.